# Transferred WordPress to new server - won't find images

Tags: wordpress

I moved a WordPress site to a new server and now in the admin media section all the images are shown without preview.

I moved all the images (whole wp-uploads folder) to the new server and updated the path in the database. When I click on an image on the media section and copy the URL to the URL bar, the image is displayed in the browser.
I tried the "Regenerate Thumbnails" plugin but then errors appear: (ID 3596) failed to resize. The error message was: The originally uploaded image file cannot be found at

I checked the path in the DB but it looks right (when I copy the path in the URL bar, the image is shown).
I also tried to give 777 permissions to all the files and folders in wp-content/uploads - didn't solve it.

Another thing - most probably connected to this - is, that all the custom fields with images are empty now. When I try to set an image which is already in the db (without a preview) and save the post - the image is gone again. When I upload a new image, it works.

Do you have any ideas about that?